# Safari doesn't display embedded images in SVG

Tags: html, svg, safari

We’ve created our team profile at themforest.net as SVG image with embedded photos. This photos are  encoded with base64 and embedded in SVG like this

```
<g>
    <image overflow="visible" width="225" height="225" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/…….AUB//9k=" transform="translate(373.663 1273)"/>
</g>
```

It works perfectly in all browsers except Safari, in which SVG `<image>` elements are not displayed. You can open the following link in Safari to see the problem http://gozha.net/test/index.html. Placing SVG image as `<object>` or `<embed>` would solve the problem, but it’s not allowed by themeforest.net.

Can anyone suggest another solution?

Comment: You're embedding the svg as an <img> and Safari does not yet support nesting images i.e. displaying a png in an SVG that itself is an image.

Comment: Display the images in the html page in the position they are supposed to be in I guess i.e. unnest them. Is that possible?